# Invalid column name 'vehicle_userId': Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: hibernate

```
package model;

  import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERDETAILS")
public class UserDetails {
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    private Date joineddate;
    private String description;
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    @OneToOne
    public Vehicle getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }


    public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }


    public void setJoineddate(Date joineddate) {
        this.joineddate = joineddate;
    }


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getJoineddate() {
        return joineddate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "User_Name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
}
```

Here I am creating userdetails table

```
  package model;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Vehicle {
        private int vehicleId;
        private String vehicleName;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="userId")
        public int getVehicleId() {
            return vehicleId;
        }

        public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
            this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
        }

        public String getVehicleName() {
            return vehicleName;
        }

        public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
            this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
        }

    }
```

Here I am creating vehicle table using one to one mapping

```
package hibernate;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

//import model.Address;
import model.UserDetails;
import model.Vehicle;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserName("bhagyasri");
        user.setDescription("bhagyasri's description");
        user.setJoineddate(new Date());

        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle.setVehicleName("hero");

        user.setVehicle(vehicle);

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.save(vehicle);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```

I am getting error like this

```
Jan 16, 2015 4:17:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
Jan 16, 2015 4:17:43 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Invalid column name 'vehicle_userId'.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
```

Hibernate configuration

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.219\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=train</property>
        <property name="connection.username">train</property>
        <property name="connection.password">tspl@123</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="model.UserDetails" />
        <mapping class="model.Vehicle" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is my configuration file.. I am getting Invalid column name 'vehicle_userId': SQLGrammarException I am not getting what is the exact problem Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you just put `@OneToOne` on some mapping (`vehicle` in your case), the default expected column name is `<field_name>_<target_id_column_name>` which in your case resolves to `vehicle_userId`, because field name is `vehicle` and you have `@Column(name="userId")` on `Vehicle#getVehicleId()`.

First, the column for `vehicleId` is probably wrong (because it is named **user**Id). So, change that to

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="vehicleId")
    public int getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }
```

and in `UserDetails` change to this

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
```

This will work if you have column `USERDETAILS.VEHICLE_ID`.

Comment: Again its throwing the same error     Invalid column name 'vehicle_vehicleId'.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any more mappings to `Vehicle`? Can you turn on SQL logging and update the question with it?